# exception report between two tables

Tags: mysql

I need to run some kind of exception report between two tables.

> Table 1
>       **Login**

[image]

> Table 2 
>   **Scan**

[image]

Now for Table Login, the boxes gets log into the system with the batch separate, but in Scan it combined the box and the batch.

I'm trying to ascertain which boxes have not been scanned, but have been logged.

So I written the below script but its not giving me the correct answer as the result is the boxes are both logged and scanned. Some strange reason??

```
SELECT distinct CONCAT_WS('-', box, batch) As box
FROM   login a
WHERE  a.profid = '46'
and dt between '2018/01/01 00:00:01am' and '2018/05/25 23:59:59 PM'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   scan b
                       WHERE  b.profid = '6'
                              AND a.box = b.boxname)
```

Were I'm I going wrong?
Thank you

Comment: You've given us sample data, which is good, but you haven't explain how these two tables are related at all.  How may we _join_ these two tables, and what is your expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have connected the Box = Box name in the scrip, I had to combine the box and the batch in the first part of my select statement, and I fear this is were I'm going wrong?

Comment: Thanks, I see this now.  Do you see that the `box` and `boxname` columns are very different data.  I think this join condition is your problem.  Maybe you can comment on this.

Comment: So, I'm trying to combine the box and the batch number to match the Scan table, this is how the front end system does it. (stupid I know) So I'm trying to do the same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I get this error Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks mostly OK, except that the join condition between the two tables looks wrong, and it won't work based on the data you showed us.  Try this version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('-', box, batch) AS box
FROM login a
WHERE
    a.profid = '46' AND
    dt >= '2018-01-01' AND dt < '2018-05-26' AND
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM scan b
               WHERE b.profid = '6' AND b.boxname LIKE CONCAT('%', a.box, '%'));
```

The critical change I made was to add the following condition to the `EXISTS` subquery:

```
b.boxname LIKE CONCAT('%', a.box, '%')
```

This makes sense, if, for example, you were trying to match box `DSDEN182` against box name `DSDEN182-BATCHG77899M`.

Side note: While the above query may work and unblock you for the moment, the join condition uses both `LIKE` and a string concatenation.  This is a very costly comparison.  For better long term performance, consider creating proper join columns on both the `login` and `scan` tables.